# How do I avoid the "?" on created files with user-input name?

Tags: c, string, file

I was doing some tests with Files in C, and one of these tests was to create a file with the name insterted by the user, but I noticed that every file I created with the insrted name finished with "?". I'm assuming it's a special character, since I have never insterted a question mark in the path string I used to get the path to the file, but I'm not sure what this character is, and I'm curious to know how to remove it from the string.

I also noticed that this code created the file even if it doesn't exists. I don't know why.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>

 const int DIM = 1024;


 int main()
 {
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char path[DIM];
    do
    {
            printf("\nFile path: ");
            fgets(path, 1024, stdin);
            fp = fopen(path, "w");
            if(fp == NULL)
            {
                    perror("Error: ");
                    free(fp);
                    printf("Retry? [y/n]");
                    scanf("%c", &c);
                    getchar();
            }
    }while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y');


 }
```

Comment: It's a newline (`'\n'`).

Comment: Do you know if replacing it with '\0' may solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, zapping the newline with a null byte will solve the problem.  `path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = '\0';` is one way.

Comment: Another way: `*strchr( path, '\n' ) = '\0' ;`

Comment: Note that learning to use a debugger to solve issues like this will be far more efficient that posting a question for every problem you may encounter.  In this case for example, a debugger will have shown the newline in the string, so you would not have been left guessing.